# change image of UIBarButton

Tags: iphone, image, ios4, uibarbuttonitem

My target is to change the Image of an UIBarButton (which i use as IBOutlet) programmatically.

I found this solution on stackoverflow [change-image-of-uibutton-with-other-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547188/change-image-of-uibutton-with-other-image). but this is not working on iOS 4.2.

Can anyone help me with that.
Simon

I tried:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: 
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"play" ofType:@"png"]];
playButton.image = image;
```

---

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"play" ofType:@"png"]];UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"play" ofType:@"png"]];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIButton* someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
playButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:someButton];

[someButton release];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to put an image to a button use following code.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"play" ofType:@"png"]];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

UIButton* someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
playButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:someButton];
```

Comment: a shorter method to load UIImage `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];`